# Reset height of a div after expansion with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, resize

I wanted to create an expanding div when the user clicks on it so that they can see the rest of the information.
I have managed to do that. What I want to do now is to make it so the height of the div changes when the user clicks on the div again.

Here is my script:

```js
$(".module").one('click', function () {
    $(this).height(400)
        .css({
        cursor: "auto"
    });
});
```

Here is my css:

```css
.module {
    width:270px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Comment: Try the `jQuery .toggleClass() method` [more info here](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way by mixing jQuery and CSS. Try this, put those CSS :

```
.module {
    width:270px;
    height:200px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.module.clicked{
    height : 400px;
    cursor : auto;
}
```

Then use this code :

```
$('.module').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
})
```

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2NeD2/

Comment: Hi, awesome fast response, but its not working for me.
 <script>
        $('.module').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
</script>

CSS:
.module {
 width:270px;
 height:200px;
 float:left;
 padding:5px;
 overflow:hidden;
 cursor:pointer;
}

.module.clicked{
 height:400px;
 cursor:auto;
}

Comment: One quick question, is the tag `script` at the bottom of your page or in the header? Also, any error in console?

Comment: its just after the div I want to expand: 
<div class="module">
         <h1>LOGIN</h1>
            <p>Maecenas sit amet velit et neque blandit laoreet. Nullam porttitor justo elit, quis elementum ipsum volutpat sit amet. Curabitur non mauris interdum, vestibulum urna vitae,</p>
        </div>
        <script>
        $('div.module').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
</script>

Comment: It's working now, I had a . before the toggle class clicked. Thank you heaps for your help.